# JavaScript search bar with Kendo UI Panelbar

Tags: javascript, search, kendo-ui, searchbar, kendo-panelbar

Can someone please help me with search bar for Kendo UI Panelbar.

1. When search I want it display on **type='program'**. Example if I search *account* the programs that have account words should appear.
2. Currently it not working at all. It just expand all my panelbar program. :(

Here i provide [dojo demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UToyUXuY)

My javascript

```
function myFunction() {

var panelbar = $("#panelbar").data("kendoPanelBar");
panelbar.expand($("li", panelbar.element));
//panelbar.collapse($("li", panelbar.element));

var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("panelbar");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }     
}
}
```

basically my nested list looks like this

```
<ul id="panelbar">
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..."> 
<li type="module">Agencies &amp; Groups
    <ul>
    <li type="category">Agency &amp; Booker
    <ul>
    <li type="program">Agency &amp; Booker</li>
    <li type="program">Region</li>
    <li type="program">Sub Region</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li type="program">Agency Category</li>
    <li type="program">Agency Contract</li>
    <li type="program">Agency Overview</li>
    </ul>
</li>   
<li type="module">Call Charge &amp; Billing
    <ul>
    <li type="category">JDS
    <ul>
    <li type="program">JDS Room Mapping</li>
    <li type="program">JDS Room Status</li>
    <li type="program">DS Interface</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li type="category">Operator Panel
    <ul>
    <li type="program">Wake Up Call</li>
    <li type="program">Operator Panel</li>
    </ul>
    </li>       
    <li type="program">Call Code</li>
    <li type="program">Charge Rate</li>
    <li type="program">Property PABX</li>
    <li type="program">Call Transaction</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here i provide [dojo demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UToyUXuY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `<LI>` `type` attribute is for bullet types.  Place your types values (i.e. hierarchy level categorization values) in the class attribute. Change

```
<li type="category" label=""><span class="k-icon ehors-subfolder-icon"></span>Account's Ledger …
```

to

```
<li class="category" label=""><span class="k-icon ehors-subfolder-icon"></span>Account's Ledger ….
```

An `id` value should be unique among all the DOM elements (except maybe radio buttons).  The leafs all have spans with the same id value, `id="spanpanelbar"`.  Place those in a class attribute as well.  Change

```
<li type="program"><span id="spanpanelbar" class="k-icon ehors-folderopen-icon"></span>General Ledger</li>
```

to

```
<li class="program"><span class="spanpanelbar k-icon ehors-folderopen-icon"></span>General Ledger</li>
```

The search match result processing is changing only the style `display` property of the leafs.  Change the processing to add a class to the `<li>`, corresponding to the search result condition.

```
style
.program.nomatch {display:block; color: lightgray } /* or simply display: none */
.program.match   {display:block;  }

javascript
match = $(this).text().match(searchRegEx);
$li = $(this);
$li.toggleClass("match", (match!=null)).toggleClass("nomatch",(match==null));
```

See this [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/ifeTEMoR/3), an update of your original one.  It has bonus code for:

- waiting for typing to stop
- highlighting the matched fragment

[image]

The PanelBar widget is a hierarchical viewer.  The items in the path to a program must be displayed in order to see the program. In order to display only paths to found programs you would:

- At search start set all items to have *nomatch* class (hide everything)
- When a match is made, set the program and it's parent items to have *match* class (unhide path to program)

Example:

```
    // hide top and middle tier so they wont show if there are no
    // subordinate programs that match

    $("li.category").toggleClass("nomatch", true).toggleClass("match",false);
    $("li.module")  .toggleClass("nomatch", true).toggleClass("match",false);

    // evaluate each program for matching the search term

    $("#panelbar li.program").each(function() { 
      var match, $li, $span, textnode, element;

      match = $(this).text().match(searchRegEx);
      $li = $(this);

      // hide/display programs according to match result

      $li.toggleClass("match", (match!=null))
         .toggleClass("nomatch",(match==null));

      // display items in path when match made

      if (match!=null) {
        $li.parentsUntil("#panelbar", "li")
          .toggleClass("match",true)
          .toggleClass("nomatch",false);
      }
```

[dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/ifeTEMoR/3)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Yes, it works like I want when search, but how to do it only display a **program** only. For example, when search word **mana**, result will display _Ledger Management_ & _Group Management_ only, So it not expand unnecessary thing. Its possible to do? Please help.

Comment: You can collapse all and expand up through a matching li.program's .parentsUntil(), expanding the tiers that lead to it.  Or similarly with match/nomatch class toggling on an expanded panelbar (Dojo updated).

Comment: Thanks again Richard! It has been an hour I try to edit your dojo sample, but not working. After search a program, how to display back kendo Panelbar back to normal,  Example after search, then I clicked on backspace I want to display back all the programs.. Thanks again, you help me a lot.

Comment: Either 1. add a reset button - click handler toggles all the match and nomatch classes off, 2. look at code closely, remove `if (filter.length < 3) return;  // only search 3 or more characters in searchTerm` line use to prevent searching on very little,( or do the reset when searchTerm length is 0. )

Comment: sorry my bad not display all the program, but it collapse all the panelbar.  `panelbar.collapse($("li", panelbar.element));` if I clicked on backspace.

Comment: Thank you for you help!

Comment: @Nixoderm be sure to follow up with more than a comment.  When you get see an acceptable answer you can mark it and up vote it.  See SO topic [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)